# Hide State in Haskell - Lazyset

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to build a datastructure in Haskell that allows efficient lookup in an ordered, infinite list.

If this was Java, I'd do something like this:

```
class LazySet<T> {

    private Iterator<T> source;
    private NavigableSet<T> set;

    public LazySet(Iterator<T> source){
         this.source = source;
         this.set = new TreeSet<T>() ;               
    }

    public boolean contains(T elem){
        // Fetch items from the source into the set until the element(or one greater than it)
        // has been found
        while (this.set.ceiling(elem) == null){
                if (this.source.hasNext()){
                    this.set.add(this.source.next());
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
        }
        return this.set.contains(elem);
    }    
}
```

Now while this class clearly has state, that state is purely for optimization and does not affect the user of the class. So It can be used in a functional manner.

The Haskell equivalent of this class would be stateful.

Probably something like this:

```
type LazySet a = (Set a, [a])

member :: Ord a => LazySet a -> a -> (Bool, LazySet a)
```

And that would force the user to explicitly pass the LazySet around, which makes it much harder to use.

Is there a way to tell haskell: Yes this thing has state, but treat it as if it didn't?

Comment: That's what a monad is all about.

Comment: I should add: Without monad. That's just a good way to pass the state around.

Comment: You might like Chris Okasaki's Purely Functional Data Structures. I believe he has an implementation in there of a lazy and potentially infinite set with good asymptotics. In short: keep a list of sets of exponentially increasing size.

Comment: Excellent question, this would actually be extremely useful and seems one of the cases where Haskell has a hard time getting on par with C++ or Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. If your function is stateful, Haskell *forces* you to declare it in the type. There are many ways, including `State`, `ST`, and `IO`, but you must use one of them.

Although it may seem restrictive at first, I think this is ultimately a good thing. It makes it much easier to trust library code when you know the types aren't lying.

Comment: there is no state there. it's an XY problem. the input is *ordered*, non-decreasing (otherwise OP's `contains` is simply incorrect).

Comment: @WillNess I think there are really two entangled questions here. One is "How do I implement an infinite set?" and the other is "How do I hide the fact that my operations are stateful?". My read is that the former was just intended to be a background example to use to discuss the latter, so I answered the latter. But see also my comment above, which discusses the former a bit as well (and foreshadows both the other answers).

Comment: ah, yes; haven't noticed it before (past its few starting words). indeed. but it's a well known and simple trick. my reading of the Q is literal: have infinite, ordered (apparently, non-decreasing) list with good asymptotics lookup (achieved in Java by dynamically growing internally maintained set, apparently -- and since the internal object is otherwise unobservable, indeed *"functional"* as per OP, viz. *no state* -- so, achievable in Haskell, with laziness as usual). *Infinite set* absent the requirement of orderedness makes no sense though, because what was missing can suddenly appear!

Comment: (achievable in Haskell-without-Monads that is, again as per OP's request).

Comment: the interesting part, thus, is this: having something maintained internally in an imperative setting, well-behaving and non-observable otherwise (so, *"encapsulated"*), is it always representable in "simple" (non-monadic) Haskell? Can it always be treated as "functional" / "pure" ? I think, yes.

Comment: @WillNess I agree it is likely possible to transform any such hidden-mutable code to pure Haskell, but I wonder whether it's always possible with _at most logarithmic overhead_.

Comment: @leftaroundabout That's what I was wondering. I released a hackage module https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lazyset that uses the trick with the trees that grow to the right (which has been proposed in some of the other answers). But I am left wondering if that is the best way to do it. It fetches more elements than necessary from the list, which is supoptimal.

Comment: @KarlsFriend well, see my answer – a Trie only needs to fetch the elements that are actually used. Of course my answer will still consume _the entire list_ if the element is _not_ found (as it has to, in order to proove the element isn't there in a possibly-decreasing list), but it's easy to include an abort condition if you know the list is sorted.

Comment: BTW: nice that you've made this into a package, but please don't export [`fromList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lazyset-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-Set-Lazy.html#v:fromList) like that – it's easy to think this should work with non-ascending lists too.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an XY problem. Put your source through

```
import Data.List ( unfoldr )
import Control.Arrow ( (***) )
import qualified Data.List.Ordered as O

  (\ chunks -> [ (head chunk, to_balanced_tree nlevels chunk) 
                 | (nlevels, chunk) <- chunks] )
  . unfoldr (\ (xs,n) -> case xs of [] -> Nothing;
        _ -> Just ( (,) n *** flip (,) (n+1) $ splitAt (2^n-1) xs)
  . flip (,) 2
  . O.nub
```

and do the lookups in its result – the lazy list of trees, each tree deeper than the previous one so containing roughly twice as much elements, which should make the lookup logarithmic overall.

Each thus constructed tree comes bundled with its minimum (leftmost) element. Constructing the balanced tree (of the form `data Tree a = Leaf | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)`) from an increasing list of its intended elements and the given depth (known in advance) is pretty standard.

A lookup on this list will only force as much of a source as is needed (well, more or less) to determine the membership, because of Haskell's laziness.

Since your source is already ordered (non-decreasing), `O.nub` spends *O(1)* time on each input element, removing all duplicates and leaving just one unique element in its wake. You *did* say your source is *ordered*, and from the code for your `contains` it should be non-decreasing, otherwise that code is simply incorrect.

`Data.List.Ordered` comes from the `data-ordlist` package.

Comment: I don't think this adresses the question, because you need the entire input to even construct the ordered list.

Comment: @leftaroundabout my understanding of the question and the code in it is that the input comes in already sorted - "ordered", as the OP says. Also the code seems to operate under that assumption. because without that assumption `contains` is just incorrect.

Comment: True; I didn't properly read the question. That makes the whole topic a lot less interesting, though...

Answer (score 1):

*This answer assumes the input list comes **not** already sorted. If you know it is in ascending order, then the problem is actually quite easy, as explained by Will Ness.*

---

You can do this with a memo-trie. Basically the trick is to replace the mutable-*structure* set type with a *static structure*, which can then simply exploit Haskell's native lazyness. The important thing about the static structure is to have a sequence of ever-larger subtries.

```
import Data.List (partition)

data PTrie a = SPTrie a :∧∧: PTrie a
data SPTrie a = NIT | Leaf a | SPTrie a :∧: SPTrie a

fromList :: [(Int, a)] -> PTrie a
fromList = go 0 1
 where go i₀ nC l = chunk :∧∧: go (i₀+nC) (nC*2) rest
        where (chunkSrc, rest) = partition ((<i₀+nC) . fst) l
              chunk = goS i₀ nC chunkSrc
       goS _ _ [] = NIT
       goS _ 1 ((_,k):_) = Leaf k
       goS i₀ nC l = goS i₀ nC' lChunk :∧: goS (i₀+nC') nC' rChunk
        where nC' = nC`quot`2
              (lChunk, rChunk) = partition ((<i₀+nC') . fst) l

llookup :: Int -> PTrie a -> Maybe a
llookup = go 1
 where go nC i (chunk :∧∧: rest)
        | i < nC     = goS nC i chunk
        | otherwise  = go (nC*2) (i-nC) rest
       goS _ _ NIT = Nothing
       goS _ _ (Leaf a) = Just a
       goS nC i (lChunk:∧:rChunk)
        | i<nC'      = goS nC' i lChunk
        | otherwise  = goS nC' (i-nC') rChunk
        where nC' = nC`quot`2
```

Comment: Please test this. I would be especially interested in how it compares performance-wise to your Java solution.

Comment: yes, creating the lazy sequence of geometrically growing substructures is precisely the idea of my answer. also, what is `Int` in `[(Int, a)]`? Where does it come from? The source is `[a]`, is it not? Similarly the lookup is supposed to be for `a`, not for `Int`. It's a *membership* test.

Comment: Well, a membership test [isn't that useful](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/), so I added an associated-value type `a`. The `Int` corresponds to the `T` in the question; it would be possible to extend this to a whole lot of other types (à la [`HasTrie`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie-0.6.8/docs/Data-MemoTrie.html#t:HasTrie)), but an `Ord` instance is not sufficient.

Comment: I basically read it as asking for an efficient `membr 77737 [3,10,..]` kind of thing.